# How to negate only least significant bits?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Starting from the position of the highest order 1 bit, how can I negate that bit and all lower order bits?

### Example (C#)

```
int inputNumber = 0b_10001;
inputNumber = ~inputNumber; // bitwise complement

int expectedNumber = 0b_000000000000000000000000000_01110;
uint actualNumber  = 0b_111111111111111111111111111_01110; // almost, but not quite
```

### Details

`0b` is just a marker to start writing the number in binary. The `_` is just a separator to make it visually easier to follow (but still valid C# code). Example: `0b_1010_1111` is actually `10101111` in binary.

I feel I'm close to the solution - I need to make a mask to get rid of the unwanted bits, but I'm not sure how.

How can I get from `10001` to `01110`, basically negating each bit, but without having the leading `1`s?

Comment: @njuffa, that mask will only work for that specific number, not all of them. I have to count the number of set bits and have a mask for those only, but still I can't figure out how.

Comment: This common method of right-contiguous mask construction will create a contiguous group of 1-bits to the right of the most significant 1-bit, all the way down to bit 0. Example: `0b_10001` will turn into `0b_11111`. I am assuming a well-defined right-shift operator, which in C and C++ means you would want to use an `unsigned` integer type for this data. I don't know how C# defines right shifts, in particular with potentially negative signed integer types. With the mask in place, you can then use `(0 - x) & m` to perform the desired bit-field negation.

Comment: @njuffa, I tried the mask from your first comment, but I'm getting `11101` instead of `11111`. The second bit is not set (I did use unsigned and C++). Example online: http://cpp.sh/7ipif

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Correct code: `m = x; m = m | (m >> 16); m = m | (m >> 8); m = m | (m >> 4); m = m | (m >> 2); ; m = m | (m >> 1);`

Comment: @njuffa, wow, this works! Thanks! Would you like to post an answer so I can upvote & accept to give you credit for your help?